# How to fix out of sync video/ audio in Windows Movie Maker

Tags: windows-movie-maker

A client has asked us to put together a simple video and as we're a web/ print design company we don't have any video software.

The Macs wouldn't recognise the file format but the Windows 7 PCs would, so we thought that Windows Movie Maker would be an easy option. Years ago I used the original version to throw together simple videos and it worked quite well.

After importing some video clips, dragging and trimming, the video and audio is now badly out of sync towards the end of the video - to the point where it's playing audio from outside of the trim points.

Unfortunately we're quite a way through this so would really like to find a fix rather than starting again.

I've had a Google search of this problem but I'm not keen on taking advice from people who TYPE IN CAPS LOL!

So I was wondering if the Superuser community had any experience with this problem and how to fix/ stop it.